# Google Calendar: Query Custom Parameter with Special Chars

Tags: c#, google-api

I am building an extension which syncs a local calendar with Google Calendar. To do this, I am setting a field on each Google event with a corresponding client-side ID.

This ID can have characters besides 0-9 A-Z, e.g. `TCU];!K!,9795897484326`. It seems like the `]` is the character which is messing up the query, since I am using `extq=[CustomID:TCU];!K!,9795897484326]`.

I tried to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TCU];!K!,9795897484326")` which replaced `]` with `%5D`, but the request still failed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "but the request still failed" - What was the error message that Google threw back to you?

Comment: @StevenV: `Invalid value for extq parameter: [CustomID:TCU];!K!,9795897484326]`

Comment: Looks like the correct format for the extended property is `[{property name}:{property value}]`. You need to follow that format and remove the invalid `;!K!,9795897484326]` at the end, or put that information into another extended property.

Comment: @StevenV: The entire ID which I need to search for is `TCU];!K!,97958974843261`. I need to somehow escape or entitize the `]` character to allow a query on the entire ID.

Comment: I'm no Google API expert, but go with the obvious \ escape character, beyond that you may have hit a limitation with the API. If you pay for support with Google, maybe open a ticket with Google Support?

Comment: @StevenV: What is that escape character?

Comment: Edited my comment, apparently the code block ate the backslash.

Comment: @StevenV: Tried the backslash, got `Invalid value for extq parameter: [CustomID:TCU\];!K!,9795897484326]`